# Excel: Countifs on Multiple Columns and Only on Visible Rows (Filtering)

Tags: excel, filtering, countif

I've seen several forum posts with the answer to this question, but I can't really understand how it's supposed to work, so I figured I'd come here for an explanation.

I have three columns:

CITY........|.Attribute 1.|.Attribute 2.|
Chicago..|........1........|........1........|
Chicago..|........1........|..................|
Boston....|........1........|........1........|
Chicago..|..................|..................|
Boston....|..................|..................|
Boston....|..................|........1........|
Chicago..|........1........|........1........|
Chicago..|........1........|........1........|

I want to get a count of the number of times a city has a "1" in Attribute 1 and Attribute 2. Normally, you would use COUNTIFS (=COUNTIFS(B2:B9,"1",C2:C9,"1"))which would give you the value of 4 - Rows 2, 4, 8, and 9.

But I want to be able to filter this list on the fly, and only be able to see data for Chicago rows, for instance. And thus, want to see the value of 3 - Rows 2, 8, and 9. But when the data is filtered, I still get the value of 4.

What code do I need to insert into my cell to get the value of 3 after filtering my list to only show Chicago, if I want to see when a city has a "1" in both Attribute 1 and Attribute 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to note that `subtotal()` is aware of which rows are hidden. e.g. `subtotal(109,b:b)` would result in 4 if a filter is applied to show only Chicago. Does anyone have a comprehensive list of filter-aware functions?

Comment: @MattClarke `Subtotal` was my first thought too.  Can't think of a way to do it directly.  But with a helper column to identify the required rows, `Subtotal` would do the job

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work for Chicago?:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9, "Chicago", B2:B9,"1", C2:C9, "1")
```

This would not require you to filter the data.

Answer (score 0):

A variant of this could be used:

```
SUMPRODUCT((Attribute 1.=Satisfactory)*(SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(AW3,ROW(tblStudentProgress[D3 Activity])-MIN(ROW(tblStudentProgress[D3 Activity])),0))))
```

Answer (score -1):

You could also create a helper column and sum attributes 1 and 2. If your helper column row equals 2 then you know both attributes exist. You could take this one step further and use concatenate to combine "Chicago" and your sum. And then filter by Chicago2.

Comment: This does not address the requirement to count only visible rows